# Correcting Myopia with a Diverging Lens

Tags: optics, visible-light, biophysics, vision

My textbook says that a diverging lens works by rendering the object a virtual image at the myopic eye’s far point. However, wouldn’t the eye then perceive an object farther than its far point *at the far point*, rather than where it truly is, beyond the far point? For example, if the far point of the eye is 30 cm, and you place something that’s 50 cm away from it, a diverging lens will cause the image to form at 30 cm, allowing the eye to see it with its lengthened shape. But why do we still perceive that object to be at 50 cm? If the image is at 30 cm, why do we not see it at 30 cm?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "perceive it at 50 cm". The eye would still focus at 30 cm (what it considers "infinity"). But an object at 50 cm, previously not in focus, can become focused with the aid of a diverging lens. Maybe you need to clarify your question - or perhaps I just answers your question...?

Comment: @Floris As in, why don’t we consciously think that that object is 30 cm away? Why do we consciously see it as being 50 cm away?

Comment: Size and stereoscopic vision?

Answer (score 1):

There are several mechanisms that the human brain-eye system use to estimate distance.

The main one is [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax), either because you have two eyes, or because you move the head one side and the other.

Another one is perspective: farther objects just look smaller.

The eye focal length, while useful to estimate distance, is quite secondary. But yes, you are right, if you close the other eye and keep the head still and ignore the apparent size, with diverging lens the objects will look a bit farther away.

But if fact, you could consider that a myopic eye actually see objects nearer than they really are, since they need less accomodation effort. That's why myopic children suffer more from [exotropia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotropia), while hyperopic children suffer more from [esotropia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esotropia).